# Is it possible to add a .java file to my chrome extension?

Tags: java, google-chrome-extension

Is it possible to add  a .java file to my chrome extension along with other files like manifest,html,js.

Can i connect my chrome extension to my database using JDBC ? Do I have to add a .java file along with my other chrome extension files?

Comment: Whoa, for a moment there you were asking a *completely* different question...

Comment: I got the answer for that.

Comment: Yeah, but you can't just change your question to be something totally different.  If you want to ask a new question, you can feel encouraged to ask it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [Java and Google Chrome Browser](https://www.java.com/en/download/faq/chrome.xml) official FAQ page:

> Google's Chrome version 45 and above have dropped support for NPAPI, and therefore Java Plugin do not work on these browsers anymore.

So, no, you cannot use `.java` files inside the Chrome browser.